# triple sum in matlab

Tags: matlab, sum

I want to compute the following sum :

[image]

I have tried using the following code :

```
 I = imread('C:\Users\Billal\Desktop\image.png');
[x,y,z]=size(I);
x=(1:x) ;
y=(1:y) ;
z=(1:z) ;
 Fx=ones(size(x));
 Fy=ones(size(y));
Fz=ones(size(z));
X=x*Fy';
Y=Fx*y';
Z=z*Fz'; 
 f=I(X,Y,Z);
sum1 = sum(f(:));
[x1,y1,z1]=size(I);
total = sum1/(x1*y1*z1);
```

But the result is 0 . I could not figure out where is the problem ? I am following this tutorial .

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/126366

Please help me to solve this question .

Comment: Did you do any debugging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in a single step:

```
result=1/prod(size(I))* sum(I(:));
```

In the end, the equation just adds up values of the whole image.

The question you link to needs to sum over *values* of `x` and `y`. You don't, you just need to sum over *indexes*, thus there is no need of all those `Fx,Fy` things

Comment: @IccheGuri Glad to help ;) Consider accepting it as the answer

Comment: or sum(I(:)) / numel(I)

Comment: ...or just mean(I(:)).

Comment: Can you help me in this question ? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191109/triple-sum-in-matlab