# How to determine contrast of an image according to formula in matlab

Tags: matlab, sum

I want to determine contrast of an image in matlab . Here is the formula of contrast of a image :

[image]

I am able to find the brightness B of image accordinbg to following code :

```
I=imread('autumn.tif')
result=1/prod(size(I))* sum(I(:))
```

[The above code is taken from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42856069/6379197)

But how can I determine contrast according to the above formula ? Please help me .

Comment: *Try something*! And then show us so we can help fix your specific problem...

Comment: How can I calculate triple sum in matlab ?

Comment: How is this different from [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856017/triple-sum-in-matlab)?

Comment: You have a 3D matrix `I`, [use `sum` 3 times, once for each dimension](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html)... and as @excaza points out, your last question today literally had this triple sum in it!

Comment: This just looks like the formula for the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Discrete_random_variable)... `std(I(:))`?

Comment: @Wolfie It would have to be `std(I(:),1)`. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/std.html#bune5v_-10

Comment: @Wolfie This *indeed* is standard deviation. You can post that  as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answer . [Beaker helps me a lot for this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377097/beaker) . Here is the code :

```
I=imread('autumn.tif');
B=1/prod(size(I))* sum(I(:))
contrast = sqrt(1/prod(size(I))*sum(power((I(:)-B),2)))
```

Hope this may help someone .